# Bad request (400) (unsupported syscall) when trying to reach container in Google Cloud Run

Tags: django, docker, google-cloud-run

I have successfully deployed a Google Cloud Run instance, its showing a green checkmark and I get an address to access the container on. I can also see that the logs show that uwsgi is booted. When trying the container locally I can access it on the port I give it...

I suspect that the incorrect booting of the system is due to this line:

> 019-12-04T21:44:45.834539783ZContainer Sandbox Limitation: Unsupported
> syscall setsockopt(0x3,0x6,0x9,0x29eebd3f8794,0x4,0x0). Please, refer
> to https://gvisor.dev/c/linux/amd64/setsockopt for more information.
>
> 2019-12-04T21:44:45.834891693ZContainer Sandbox Limitation:
> Unsupported syscall setsockopt(0x4,0x6,0x9,0x29eebd3f8794,0x4,0x0).
> Please, refer to https://gvisor.dev/c/linux/amd64/setsockopt for more
> information.
> 2019-12-04T21:44:45.835166ZuWSGI http bound on
> 0.0.0.0:8080 fd 4 2019-12-04T21:44:45.841985Zspawned uWSGI http 1 (pid: 3)
> 2019-12-04T21:44:45.844243Zuwsgi socket 0 bound to TCP
> address 127.0.0.1:48977 (port auto-assigned) fd 3

Does anyone have any tips on getting the container to run on Cloud Run?

Comment: When you try and access the Cloud Run environment, is there any indication that the request is getting through?   What is the nature of the container you are deploying ... is it your code, packaged code, an existing image etc?

Comment: I can see in the cloud run dashboard that a get is preformed:

2019-12-04T21:45:11.105874ZGET400241 B9.9 sChrome 78 https://********run.app/
2019-12-04T21:45:11.331412Z[pid: 2|app: 0|req: 2/2] 169.254.8.129 () {48 vars in 917 bytes} [Wed Dec 4 21:45:11 2019] GET /favicon.ico => generated 26 bytes in 9 msecs (HTTP/1.

This is a django image, working locally...

Answer (score 3):

There is a **high chance** that the "unsupported syscall" log is actually not causing any problems to your application. These logs are mostly a *warning*, and most of the time applications fallback to other syscalls or options to get the job done.

(Many Cloud Run users see this warning in their logs, but most of the time their error is stemming from another issue –however this warning picks their attention so they tend to assume it's the root cause.)

Can you please try running your application locally on Docker using these instructions https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/testing/local and verify if your applications boots fine locally? (Please let me know in the comments).

<strike>In this case, the 0x9 option to `setsockopt` suggests SO_DEBUG and SO_KEEPALIVE. I'm guessing SO_DEBUG might not have been implemented. So if you're running your WSGI server in debug mode,  maybe try disabling that in your prod container?</strike>

**Update(Dec 9, 2019):** `setsockopt(0x4,0x6,0x9,..)` signature suggests 0x6=SOL_TCP, 0x9=TCP_DEFER_ACCEPT. In this case, our internal investigation revealed that gVisor does not yet support `TCP_DEFER_ACCEPT` option, which is [set by uWSGI](https://github.com/unbit/uwsgi/blob/cff962041975e8d7bf540bd121cb2268395cabde/core/socket.c#L751). So we've started to work on addressing this in gVisor. In the meanwhile, this application most likely won't work on Cloud Run. Hope you try again later.

Comment: Hello! Thanks for your reply! Yes, it works fine locally, I send in the port and can see that the correct port is issued to uwsgi. I can also use the Django site when accessing localhost.

The container is not running in debug (unless Ive done something obviously faulty), Ive printed the setting:
2019-12-04T21:45:04.735518ZDebug is false

Comment: Are you still having a bad request error when you make a request? Can you deploy a very simple app with the same framework and see if that fails?

Comment: Yes still having the same issue, running locally has always worked... I have trired deploying an hello world example and its working fine...

Comment: Thanks we're actually investigating this. I updated some info above. It seems like gVisor is not yet fully supporting _uwsgi_.

Comment: Thank you @AhmetB! I will certainly try again, is there any way to follow the progression of this issue?

Comment: Do you have any updates on this @AhmetB? Can i try with for example gunicorn?

Comment: @AhmetB-Google  I see TCP_DEFER_ACCEPT had been implemented in gVisor, but apparently Cloud Run's gVisor hasn't been updated yet? (https://github.com/google/gvisor/pull/1600)

Comment: Getting the same error in Cloud Run when starting a container with Java-based gRPC server inside. I get the error on the first client request after which my server shuts down. Locally everything works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

In the troubleshooting documentation for Cloud Run, we see a section called "Is your issue caused by a limitation in the container sandbox?"  (See [here](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/troubleshooting#sandbox)).  Following the links we find that the container runs in a special [sandbox](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/reference/container-contract#sandbox) and then we see that there are OS constraints (limitations).  Following this to [here](https://gvisor.dev/docs/user_guide/compatibility/linux/amd64/) we then find this line for the `setsockopt()` system call:

```
54  setsockopt  Partial Support Not all socket options are supported.
```

and I think this is the punch line.  The code running in the container is making a `setsockopt()` OS system call passing in parameters that are explicitly not supported/permitted in the gVisor runtime.  The only solution I can think of is to work back through the logic of the code that is running the container and see if we can find where that call is being made and why.  There might be options we can supply to cause that path to be avoided.

Comment: Seems strange though since this is a standard Django install, with a postgres connection that it wouldnt workn due to limitations in cloud run?

Comment: Ideally, we should be able to narrow it further.  It is likely that the syscall is being made by a JNI call which would mean that there is a statement in the Java code that is triggering that.  If we debug the execution of the Java Code and find out at what class/statement the call is failing, we will then understand the back story.  Until then, we can't really guess.  It would be like a doctor being surprised that a 21 year old patient got sick and died without knowing what they died of.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, this is not a complete answer but I don't have enough "reputations" to leave a comment!!

The exact same issue happened to me after changing my DOCKERFILE to pull the image `google/cloud-sdk:latest`. I haven't figured out a good workaround for this but my application works perfectly fine, except the fact that my logs get spammed by this warning. I am pointing this out since I believe one of the applications installed in this docker image is causing it.